# Ruby on Rails - where query with Time parse

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I select all records where the date is past?

I have "Date" column with format : '%m/%d/%Y' e.g "01/10/2017".
Column type is string, I can't change the type.

How should I write query.

Something like: `Article.where(Time.parse(:date).past?)`?

I need solution in pure RoR, without any gem.

Comment: What database? Most DBs provide some date parsing options but it is going to be DB specific. I would migrate to a real date type column ASAP though. Thats a horrible date format since it cannot simply be numerically compared like a ISO 8601 date anyways.

Comment: Since your setup is not typical please provide which DB, and a small example of what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, if your underlying database can use the MySQL [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
Article.where("STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') < ?)", Time.now)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's a string.

Comment: Updated with an answer that should work for MySQL- or you can probably do something similar if using another database implementation.

Comment: @RafalPiekara Glad to hear it's working. If this answer helped solve your question, next step is to [mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/327137). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have trouble parsing a string column to date unless you can use a native SQL function.

You may have to consider reformatting your date column to a more conventional datetime format, but you can use `chronic` for that as well.

In a migration:

```
Article.find_each do |article|
  stamp = Chronic.parse(article.date)
  article.update_attributes(date: stamp)
end
```

In short, `chronic` makes it easy to handle unconventional date formats, which you kind of have going on here. If you run the above migration you can run the following query, which is much cleaner:

`Article.where("date <= ?", Time.now)`

Comment: Hi @NickM, thank you for your response but I need the solution with pure RoR, without any gem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you:

`Article.where('date < ?', Time.now)`

This will pull all the records where the date at is before today.

EDIT:
Damn, I was writing this answer while three other people were writing the same thing. Sorry

Comment: Won't work either way since OP has the dates stored in string column.

Comment: I did not notice that, thank you. That is a problem. Although I'm not sure why he can't just rollback and change the column type, but that probably has something to do with the rest of his application.